# How do I build into a specified directory using the "prefix" option of configure?

Tags: gnu-make, glibc, configure

I am trying to build glibc 2.27 on Clear Linux, obtained here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html

According to the help, I should build into a directory outside of the source folder using the prefix command. As far as I can tell, I am doing what is described in the installation help:

> ## Configuring and compiling the GNU C Library
>
> The GNU C Library cannot be compiled in the source directory.  You
>   must build it in a separate build directory.  For example, if you have
>   unpacked the GNU C Library sources in '/src/gnu/glibc-VERSION', create
>   a directory '/src/gnu/glibc-build' to put the object files in.  This
>   allows removing the whole build directory in case an error occurs,
>   which is the safest way to get a fresh start and should always be
>   done.
>
> From your object directory, run the shell script 'configure'
>   located at the top level of the source tree.  In the scenario above,
>   you'd type
>
> ```
>  $ ../glibc-VERSION/configure ARGS...
> ```
>
> Please note that even though you're building in a separate build
>   directory, the compilation may need to create or modify files and
>   directories in the source directory.
>
> 'configure' takes many options, but the only one that is usually
>   mandatory is '--prefix'.  This option tells 'configure' where you want
>   the GNU C Library installed.  This defaults to '/usr/local', but the
>   normal setting to install as the standard system library is
>   '--prefix=/usr' for GNU/Linux systems and '--prefix=' (an empty
>   prefix) for GNU/Hurd systems.

so, I thought I was doing this correctly, but it still gave me an error about building in a different directory:

```
james@clr ~/Downloads/glibc $  ./configure --prefix=/home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for readelf... readelf
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ can link programs... yes
configure: error: you must configure in a separate build directory
```

Comment: Why do you need/want build it from source?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to create a build-directory and run `configure` script from it. Your case:

```
mkdir /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/
cd /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/
~/Downloads/glibc/configure
```

The `--prefix` option will change the install directory (`make install`).

Comment: Thanks, that got me past my problem with configure... but where do I run make install from? I ran in both /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/ and ~/Downloads/glibc/ without success.

Comment: I think should work from build directory (`cd ~/Downloads/glibc-build && make && make install`). What is your error message?

Comment: Note that doing `make install` (or, more likely `sudo make install`) is *very* likely to render your system unbootable.

Comment: Why is this error message so wrong? It should be like `configure: error: you must run configure from the targeted build directory`

Comment: How did you try build?

Answer (score 3):

The process to cross-compile `glibc` is similar to the other libraries and projects, **BUT**, In the specific case of `glibc` the folder where we **extract the project** and the folder where we generate our **configuration files** are diferent. So It's necessary to create a folder to hold our generated configuration files.

So, after you download and extract `glibc` in a folder, you have to exit this folder and create another, so run the `configure` script from this new folder.

**Example:**

```bash
# Making a folder to hold source code

cd $HOME/Downloads
mkdir glibc-build
cd glibc-build

# Downloading glibc
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/glibc-2.27.tar.gz

# Extracting glibc
tar -xvf glibc-2.27.tar.gz

# Creating folder to hold generate config files
mkdir configs_glibc && cd configs_glibc 

# Run configure script
../glibc-2.27/configure --prefix=$HOME/Downloads/glibc-build/configs_glibc
```

For the compilation and installation, you continue inside the `configs_glibc` and run:

```bash
# Compiling
make 
# Installing
make install
```