# Debugging glibc build process

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make, glibc, cc

I am am trying to install glibc on Clear Linux, and am having difficulty debugging (or even which of the many makefiles to debug).
My previous attempts are in these two threads:
[How do I build into a specified directory using the "prefix" option of configure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51062293/how-do-i-build-into-a-specified-directory-using-the-prefix-option-of-configure/51062660#51062660)
[Errors building glibc: what is wrong with the make/confgure files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071158/errors-building-glbic-what-is-wrong-with-the-make-confgure-files)

So now my problem is that when I run make, the build stops with:

```
  -I../sysdeps/nptl  -I../sysdeps/pthread  -I../sysdeps/gnu  -I../sysdeps/unix/inet  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/posix  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu/include -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/x86  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/float128  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96/include -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32  -I../sysdeps/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754  -I../sysdeps/generic  -I.. -I../libio -I.   -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/libc-modules.h -DMODULE_NAME=libc -include ../include/libc-symbols.h       -DTOP_NAMESPACE=glibc -I../soft-fp -o /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/math/s_modfl.o -MD -MP -MF /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/math/s_modfl.o.dt -MT /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/math/s_modfl.o
cc1: error: -fassociative-math disabled; other options take precedence [-Werror]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/sysd-rules:791: /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/math/s_modfl.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/james/Downloads/glibc/math'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:215: math/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/james/Downloads/glibc'
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 2
```

I suspect a clue might be in this thread, but it's a little over my head.
[associative-math with GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321011/associative-math-with-gcc)

I'm also guessing that the later errors from the makefiles are the result of whatever went wrong with associative math.

**Edit**
As requested, I ran

```
james@clr ~/Downloads/glibc-build $ make -j
```

and this was the end of the output

```
 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96/include -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32  -I../sysdeps/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754  -I../sysdeps/generic  -I.. -I../libio -I.   -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/libc-modules.h -DMODULE_NAME=libc -include ../include/libc-symbols.h  -DPIC -DSHARED     -DTOP_NAMESPACE=glibc -I../soft-fp -DASSEMBLER  -g -Werror=undef -Wa,--noexecstack   -o /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/math/s_signbit.os -MD -MP -MF /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/math/s_signbit.os.dt -MT /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/math/s_signbit.os
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/sysd-rules:791: /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/math/s_modfl.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [/home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/sysd-rules:825: /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/math/s_modf.o] Error 1
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/sysd-rules:893: /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/math/s_modff.o] Error 1
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/sysd-rules:757: /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/math/s_modff128.o] Error 1
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/sysd-rules:807: /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/math/s_modfl.os] Error 1
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/sysd-rules:841: /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/math/s_modf.os] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/james/Downloads/glibc/math'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:215: math/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/james/Downloads/glibc'
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 2
```

edit 2: more information in response to comments by Basile:
I need glibc to run some modules for Phoronix Test Suite, and in the future I will probably need it to build libraries for R. As far as I can tell, it is not included with Clear Linux (at least PTS doesn't think I have it installed), and I do not see it among the list of available bundles.
Versions:

```
    james@clr ~/Downloads $ uname -r
    4.17.1-582.native
    james@clr ~/Downloads $ gcc --version
    gcc (Clear Linux OS for Intel Architecture) 8.1.1 20180514
    Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.



Configure commands

james@clr ~/Downloads $ git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git
james@clr ~/Downloads $ cd glibc
james@clr ~/Downloads/glibc $ git checkout --track -b local_glibc-2.27 origin/release/2.27/master
Branch 'local_glibc-2.27' set up to track remote branch 'release/2.27/master' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'local_glibc-2.27'
james@clr ~/Downloads/glibc $ mkdir /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/
james@clr ~/Downloads/glibc $ cd /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/
james@clr ~/Downloads/glibc-build $ ~/Downloads/glibc/configure --prefix=/home/james/Downloads/glibc-build
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for readelf... readelf
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ can link programs... yes
checking for sysdeps preconfigure fragments... aarch64 alpha arm hppa i386 m68k microblaze mips nios2 powerpc riscv s390 sh sparc tile x86_64 checking whether gcc compiles in -mx32 mode by default... no

checking for use of fpu sysdeps directories... yes
checking for -fstack-protector... yes
checking for -fstack-protector-strong... yes
checking for -fstack-protector-all... yes
checking for assembler and linker STT_GNU_IFUNC support... yes
checking for gcc attribute ifunc support... yes
checking if compiler warns about alias for function with incompatible types... yes
checking sysdep dirs... sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64 sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64 sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86 sysdeps/x86/nptl sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64 sysdeps/x86_64/nptl sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux sysdeps/nptl sysdeps/pthread sysdeps/gnu sysdeps/unix/inet sysdeps/unix/sysv sysdeps/unix/x86_64 sysdeps/unix sysdeps/posix sysdeps/x86_64/64 sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch sysdeps/x86_64/fpu sysdeps/x86/fpu sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch sysdeps/x86_64 sysdeps/x86 sysdeps/ieee754/float128 sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96 sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64 sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64 sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32 sysdeps/wordsize-64 sysdeps/ieee754 sysdeps/generic
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether as is GNU as... yes
checking whether ld is GNU ld... yes
checking for as... as
checking version of as... 2.30, ok
checking for ld... ld
checking version of ld... 2.30, ok
checking for gnumake... no
checking for gmake... no
checking for make... make
checking version of make... 4.2.1, ok
checking for gnumsgfmt... no
checking for gmsgfmt... no
checking for msgfmt... msgfmt
checking version of msgfmt... 0.19.8.1, ok
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
checking version of makeinfo... 6.5, ok
checking for sed... sed
checking version of sed... 4.5, ok
checking for gawk... gawk
checking version of gawk... 4.2.1, ok
checking for bison... bison
checking version of bison... 3.0.5, ok
checking if gcc is sufficient to build libc... yes
checking for nm... gcc-nm
checking for python3... python3
checking LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable... ok
checking for bash... /usr/bin/bash
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for install-info... /usr/bin/install-info
checking for .set assembler directive... yes
checking linker support for protected data symbol... yes
checking linker support for INSERT in linker script... yes
checking for broken __attribute__((alias()))... no
checking whether to put _rtld_local into .sdata section... no
checking whether to use .ctors/.dtors header and trailer... no
checking for libunwind-support in compiler... no
checking whether --noexecstack is desirable for .S files... yes
checking for -z combreloc... yes
checking for linker that supports -z execstack... yes
checking for linker that supports --no-dynamic-linker... yes
checking for -static-pie... yes
checking for -fpie... yes
checking for --hash-style option... yes
checking for sufficient default -shared layout... no
checking for GLOB_DAT reloc... yes
checking linker output format... elf64-x86-64
checking for -fno-toplevel-reorder -fno-section-anchors... yes
checking for -mtls-dialect=gnu2... yes
checking whether cc puts quotes around section names... no
checking for __builtin_memset... no
checking for redirection of built-in functions... yes
checking for compiler option to disable generation of FMA instructions... -ffp-contract=off
checking if gcc accepts -fno-tree-loop-distribute-patterns with __attribute__ ((__optimize__))... yes
checking for libgd... yes
checking for is_selinux_enabled in -lselinux... no
checking for _FORTIFY_SOURCE predefine... yes
checking whether the linker provides working __ehdr_start... yes
checking for __builtin_trap with no external dependencies... yes
checking whether the C++ compiler supports thread_local... yes
running configure fragment for sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64
running configure fragment for sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64
running configure fragment for sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux
checking installed Linux kernel header files... 3.2.0 or later
checking for kernel header at least 3.2.0... ok
checking for symlinks in /home/james/Downloads/glibc-build/include... ok
running configure fragment for sysdeps/gnu
running configure fragment for sysdeps/unix/inet
running configure fragment for sysdeps/x86_64
checking for AVX512DQ support in assembler... yes
checking for AVX512 support... yes
checking for Intel MPX support... yes
checking whether -fPIC is default... no
checking whether -fPIE is default... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.make
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing default commands
```

Edit 3: The FULL output of make was too long to include, so I put it on pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/H3yGC5aj

Comment: You already have a `libc` on every Linux distribution. You don't need to install a new one

Comment: If there is a Clear Linux bundle for glibc, please link to it.

Comment: You need to explain in your question why do you need to compile the glibc on your distro. There are very rare cases where that is needed. All Linux distributions ship some libc (very often the [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) one, perhaps [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)...) and they are generally compatible. Libc is the cornerstone of every Linux system, and your distribution maker has compiled it.

Comment: BTW, did you consider using some `chroot`-ed environment? Perhaps that could help. But you really should explain in your question your motivations to compile the `glibc`. We cannot guess them, and they are very important. Explain why your distribution's `libc` is not enough for you. So **edit your question** to improve it (otherwise, it is unclear).

Comment: Also, give the precise `configure` command that you have used... and tell more about your system (what `libc` it has natively, what `gcc` version, what kernel version, etc...). However, I tend to believe that (unless explained otherwise) you don't need to compile `glibc`

Comment: Please show the complete command line before the failure, and run make *without* `-j`.

Comment: I have put the full output of make on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/H3yGC5aj

Comment: I've never done the chroot thing, it sounds like a major pain in the butt. Is that what I gotta do to move further with this?

Comment: Hey Basile, turns out you were right all along. I was misinformed about the status of glibc on my system, I ran `ldd --version" and confirmed that I had glibc. Feel free to submit that as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler command line you posed contains these flags:

`-fassociative-math -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fexceptions -ffat-lto-objects -fmerge-all-constants -fno-semantic-interposition -fno-signed-zeros -fno-stack-protector -fno-trapping-math -frounding-math -fstack-protector -ftree-loop-distribute-patterns`

However, `-fassociative-math` is one of the unsafe math optimizations, and glibc cannot be built with them because with such optimizations, the math library would produce wrong results—and as you found out, some of the required compiler flags for parts of the math library are even incompatible with them.

You did not pass these flags to `configure` or `make` explicitly, so it is most likely they come from the `CFLAGS` environment variable.  You need to unset that before calling `configure` and `make`.