# Install glibc 2.27 without root access, error you must configure in a separate build directory

Tags: gnu-make, glibc, configure

I am a client of a server and don't have root access, so I need to build glbic from binaries. I have downloaded Glibc from [this](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/) source. Here is my error log.

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ can link programs... yes
configure: error: you must configure in a separate build directory
```

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51062293/how-do-i-build-into-a-specified-directory-using-the-prefix-option-of-configure/51062660) answer so here is my command.

```
 adnan@2080Ti:~/Packages/glbic-build$./configure --prefix=$HOME/Packages/glibc-2.27/
```

I have copied all files from `glibc-2.27` to `glbic-build` , and running from `glbic-build` but it seems like both are same folder, glbic-build folder should have all files or some specific files or what. It is not clear to me. Please consider that English is not my first language, maybe I am not understanding it right.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Update:
I installed it as suggested by @MadScientist answer, but after all the hustle, when I use `~$ ldd --version` it still shows the 2.23.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't copy all the files.  Delete the `glibc-build` directory, then create it again as a completely empty directory.  Then from the `glibc-build` directory run the configure file that's in the source directory.  So, like this:

```
~/Packages$ ls
glibc-2.27     glibc-build

~/Packages$ rm -rf glibc-build

~/Packages$ mkdir glibc-build

~/Packages$ cd glibc-build

~/Packages/glibc-build$ ../glibc-2.27/configure <whatever args you want>

~/Packages/glibc-build$ make
```

(you may want to pass the `-jN` option to `make`, replacing `N` with the number of CPUs in your system, to speed up the build).

Comment: I am running in the conda env 
here is error i got. 
*** LD_LIBRARY_PATH shouldn't contain the current directory when
*** building glibc. Please change the environment variable
*** and run configure again.

Comment: output of echo  $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:

Comment: I tried outside of the conda. same error.

Comment: The problem is you should remove the `:` at the end of your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` setting.  An empty directory on that PATH implies the current directory.

Comment: done, but i think i can not install it with ../glibc-2.27/configure --disable-sanity-checks as i am not admin. so i tried with  ../glibc-2.27/configure --prefix="$HOME/local/glibc" and after make and make install i end up with warning: /home/adnan/Packages/glibc-build/elf/ldconfig: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /home/adnan/local/glibc/etc/ld.so.conf: No such file or directory
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/adnan/Packages/glibc-2.27'


and still old version 2.23

Comment: That is a different question, and not related to building or makefiles.  Maybe you can find info by searching for how to install a local version of libc and what needs to be done to allow it.